# VerticalOptions is cant be found or mismatch type between value or property

Tags: c#, .net, properties, maui, bindableproperty

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error XFC0009 No property, BindableProperty, or event found for
> "VerticalOptions", or mismatching type between value and
> property. NetflixCloneApp

I am creating a netflix clone app on visual studio and I have specified a bindable property which i'll be using in my main page but the verticaloptions view is not working with the property.

This is My MovieInfoBox.xaml.cs

```
using NetflixCloneApp.Models;

namespace NetflixCloneApp.Controls;

public partial class MovieInfoBox : ContentPage
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty MediaProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Media), typeof(Media), typeof(MovieInfoBox), null);
    public MovieInfoBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Media Media 
    { get => (Media)GetValue(MovieInfoBox.MediaProperty); 
      set => SetValue(MovieInfoBox.MediaProperty, value);
    }
}
```

This is My Models Class

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using NetflixCloneApp.Models;
using NetflixCloneApp.Services;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NetflixCloneApp.ViewModels
{
    public partial class HomeViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        private readonly TmdbService _tmdbService;
        public HomeViewModel(TmdbService tmdbService)
        {
            _tmdbService = tmdbService;
        }
        [ObservableProperty]
        private Media _trendingMovie;

        [ObservableProperty]
        private Media _selectedMedia;
        public ObservableCollection<Media> Trending { get; set; } = new();
        public ObservableCollection<Media> TopRated { get; set; } = new();
        public ObservableCollection<Media> NetflixOriginals { get; set; } = new();
        public ObservableCollection<Media> ActionMovies { get; set; } = new();

        public async Task InitializeAsync()
        {
            var trendingListTask =  _tmdbService.GetTrendingAsync();
            var netflixOriginalsListTask =  _tmdbService.GetNetflixOriginalsAsync();
            var topRatedListTask =  _tmdbService.GetTopRatedAsync();
            var actionListTask =  _tmdbService.GetActionAsync();

            var medias = await Task.WhenAll(trendingListTask,
                                            netflixOriginalsListTask,
                                            topRatedListTask,
                                            actionListTask);

            var trendingList = medias[0];
            var netflixOriginalsList = medias[1];
            var topRatedList = medias[2];
            var actionList = medias[3];

            TrendingMovie = trendingList.OrderBy(t => Guid.NewGuid())
                               .FirstOrDefault(t => 
                               !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t.DisplayTitle)
                               && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t.Thumbnail));



            SetMediaCollection(trendingList, Trending);
            SetMediaCollection(netflixOriginalsList, NetflixOriginals);
            SetMediaCollection(topRatedList, TopRated);
            SetMediaCollection(actionList, ActionMovies);

            SelectedMedia = TrendingMovie;


        }
        private static void SetMediaCollection(IEnumerable<Media> medias, ObservableCollection<Media> collecion)
        {
            collecion.Clear();
            foreach (var media in medias)
            {
                collecion.Add(media);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the MainPage Class

```
<controls:MovieInfoBox Media="{Binding SelectedMedia}"
                               VerticalOptions="End"></controls:MovieInfoBox>
```

[Error Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KffEn.png)

Comment: You're inheriting from a `ContentPage`, that indeed does not have `VerticalOptions`. Should you be using a `ContentView`?

Comment: It didn't... I did try but Content View has some limitations when it comes to basic styling of the page.

Comment: a Page always fills its container, there is no need for Vertical/Horizontal options